# How to skip grub screen and just boot to windows 7?

Tags: grub2

I tried a few things already.  this is my /etc/default screen.  This wont work.  It still brings me to the grub screen and stays there until an OS is selected.  I don't want that screen to come up.  I want to go straight into windows 7.  Any info would be nice.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: You also may set time to 1 sec so then system should boot quickly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the GRUB OS selection screen modify:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

And after you save and close run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

To **permanently delete GRUB** use a Windows 7 bootable DVD like this:

- when you see the install screen choose the `Repair your computer` option
- select `Command Prompt` option
- write these commands: `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`
- restart your PC

**You will lose the ability to boot into Linux. You'll have to use a Linux live CD to repair GRUB if you want Linux back!**